# jQuery change event not firing on input element

Tags: jquery, html, css, svg

First of all, I checked every topic similar to my problem, unfortunately, I haven't found my answer yet. I tried to combine some of the anwers, but I had no succes. (note: just started to learn jQuery)

So here is my problem:

I created a form with four text inputs and a button. Each input has a svg icon inside it and a placeholder text.

HTML:

```
<div class="first-field">
<input class="text" type="text" placeholder="Uw naam.." value="">
<svg class="unfilled" id="svg_user">
</svg>
</div>
```

(I removed the svg data since it's irrelevant.)

The svg icon is the same color as the placeholder. The entered text color is a bit lighter. I want to change the color of the svg icon to the same color as the entered text, but ONLY when something is entered.

First I tried to fire an alert when something is entered, to check if it knows when something was entered. I used an example from the jQuery website :

```
$( ".text" ).change(function() {
alert( "Handler for .change() called." );
});
```

This did not work and, accordingly to the documentation, it should.

I found this solution on stack, but that also won't work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.text').keyup(function () { alert('test'); });
});
```

Without the alert, i can't continue building towards a solution.
Quick summary:

SVG icon needs to change to the same color as the entered text, but ONLY when something is entered. When deleted it should change back to the color of the placeholder text.

For now, I thank you all for the help.

Comment: There is no problem with your second code. Tested.

Comment: I would suggest using `.on`  http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for need to wrap code in a `document.ready` wrapper, is because the code wants to run **instantly**, the moment it is loaded. Usually, the code runs before the DOM has been created (i.e. the page has been fully rendered) -- so some of the elements the code needs to access are not there yet -- and the code breaks.

Here is an example of using a document.ready wrapper:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="first-field">
    <input class="text" type="text" placeholder="Uw naam.." value="" />
    <svg class="unfilled" id="svg_user"></svg>
</div>
```

**javascript/jQuery:**

```
var ran=0;
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.text').keyup(function(e) { 
        if (ran == 0){
            ran++;
            alert('test');
        }
    });

}); //END document.ready
```

[Working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wrprq9e/)

---

However, if the HTML has been injected via javascript or through AJAX (via `.load()`) or something like that, then the user events will not trigger any code to run.

In that case, there is a simple solution: use jQuery's `.on()` method.

```
var ran=0;
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('keyup', '.text', function(e) { 
        if (ran == 0){
            ran++;
            alert('test');
        }
    });

}); //END document.ready
```

The above small change:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '.text', function(e) {
```

binds the event handler to the document itself, and tells it to watch for any `keyup` events involving the element with class `.text`.

[Modified jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wrprq9e/1/)

One of those should work fine.

---

Notice that the example constructed for you includes a CHECK so that the `keyup` action is not performed more than once.  You can remove that and have the code do something with every keypress:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('.text').keyup(function(e) { 
        alert('test');
    });

}); //END document.ready
```

Comment: Thnx! This worked. With this information I want to remove its current class and add a new one, similar to the entered text. Wil the svg keep the class if i remove the focus from a input field?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for my problem!
I found out that jQuery can't handle the regular 'classes' and 'id's'. So the methods    .addClass() and .removeClass() wont work.

What does work is using the .attr() method to add a new or old(default) class. Here's the code:

```
$(function(){
  $('.text').keyup(function(){
      if ($(this).val() == '') { //Check to see if there is any text entered
           //If there is no text within the input then add class 'unfilled'
            $("#svg_user").attr("class", "unfilled");
      } else {
           //If there is text in the input, then change the class from 'unfilled' to 'filled'
            $("#svg_user").attr("class", "unfilled filled");
      }
 });
});
```

Thnx for al your help getting me started!