# Checking if form is filled with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I want to check if both the email input and password input are filled before allowing the submit button to be pressed. I keep getting back that the variables stay false.

My Javscript:

```
var filled1 = false;
var filled2 = false;
setInterval(function() {
if ($(".login_email").length > 2) {
  filled1 = true;
} else {
  filled1 = false;
}
if($(".login_pass").length > 2) {
  filled2 = true;
} else {
  filled2 = false;
}
if(filled1 == true && filled2 == true) {
  $(".login_sub").css("cursor", "pointer");
  $(".login_sub").css("opacity", "1");
  $(".login_sub").attr("onclick", "document.forms['login_form'].submit();");
} else {
  $(".login_sub").css("cursor", "not-allowed");
  $(".login_sub").css("opacity", "0.6");
  $(".login_sub").attr("onclick", "");
}
}, 500);
```

and Form :

```
<form method="POST" name="login_form">
      <input type="email" name="login_email" class="login_email" placeholder="Email"/>
      <br/>
      <input type="password" name="login_pass" class="login_pass" placeholder="Password"/>
      <br/>
      <div class="login_sub" name="sub_login">Login</div>
    </form>
```

Comment: Did you try "keyup" ? Here is a useful link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29089946/check-with-jquery-if-a-value-in-an-input-element-was-entered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some extra code. Simply check the value length of the fields:

```js
setInterval(function() {
  if($(".login_email").val().length && $(".login_pass").val().length) {
    $(".login_sub").css("cursor", "pointer");
    $(".login_sub").css("opacity", "1");
    $(".login_sub").attr("onclick", "document.forms['login_form'].submit();");
  } else {
    $(".login_sub").css("cursor", "not-allowed");
    $(".login_sub").css("opacity", "0.6");
    $(".login_sub").attr("onclick", "");
  }
}, 500);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form method="POST" name="login_form">
  <input type="email" name="login_email" class="login_email" placeholder="Email"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="password" name="login_pass" class="login_pass" placeholder="Password"/>
  <br/>
  <div class="login_sub" name="sub_login">Login</div>
</form>
```

Though I personally prefer the following approach (without `setInterval()`):

```js
$(".login_sub").css("cursor", "not-allowed");
$(".login_sub").css("opacity", "0.6");
function submitForm() {
  if($(".login_email").val().length && $(".login_pass").val().length) {
    $(".login_sub").css("cursor", "pointer");
    $(".login_sub").css("opacity", "1");
    $(".login_sub").attr("onclick", "document.forms['login_form'].submit();");
  } else {
    $(".login_sub").css("cursor", "not-allowed");
    $(".login_sub").css("opacity", "0.6");
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<form method="POST" name="login_form">
  <input type="email" oninput="submitForm()" name="login_email" class="login_email" placeholder="Email"/>
  <br/>
  <input type="password" oninput="submitForm()" name="login_pass" class="login_pass" placeholder="Password"/>
  <br/>
  <div class="login_sub" name="sub_login">Login</div>
</form>
```

Comment: That works! Thank you! But just one quick question, how exactly are you checking if the inputs have any value in it with that if statement? Does .val() just check for a value?

Comment: @TristanSchlarman, in jQuery `.val()` is the function to get the value from inputs.

Comment: @TristanSchlarman, you are most welcome..... one more thing `$(".login_email").val().length && $(".login_pass").val().length` is equivalent to `$(".login_email").val().length > 0 && $(".login_pass").val().length > 0`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `required` attribute and `checkValidity()` method. Also you need a `button` to `submit` a form. There is no need of `setInterval` here

```js
let email = document.getElementById('login_email');
let password = document.getElementById('login_pass');
   
// on keyup from the input check if the field is empty, then disable the 
// submit button
$('.nt-empty').on('keyup', function() {
  if (email.checkValidity() && password.checkValidity()) {
    $('.login_sub').attr('disabled', false)
  } else {
    $('.login_sub').attr('disabled', true)
  }


})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" name="login_form">
  <input type="email" name="login_email" id="login_email" class="login_email nt-empty" placeholder="Email" required />
  <br/>
  <input type="password" name="login_pass" id="login_pass" class="login_pass nt-empty" placeholder="Password" required />
  <br/>
  <button disabled class="login_sub" name="sub_login" type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```